# Tinymce get content issue in ie8 (compatibility mode)

Tags: tinymce

I am showing the `tinymce` editor inside a modal dialog window. Sometimes while getting the editor content it is throwing a script error in IE8 (compatibility mode).

```
tinyMCE.get('testeditor').getContent()
```

The script error is :

I can not write the entire error message here but this shows me

> Line 1:
>   156 386 characters:
>   Code: 0

The URI is:

> `http://pro/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js`

Can anybody help ?

Comment: do you relly need to support IE8? if possible save yourself that kind of trouble

Comment: IE8 compatibility mode...

Comment: that is almost the same

Comment: HI, i found the solutions.   http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/11/13/dynamically-adding-and-removing-tinymce-instances-to-a-page/